# "deprecated POSIX function" `read` raises an exception

Tags: c, posix, msvc12

I am compiling a cross-platform C library (which works fine on Linux, and used to work on Windows) with MSVC (VS 2013) in Debug mode. When I call `read` from the C standard library, I sometimes get the exception:

> An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

I believe the parameters (file descriptor, buffer, length) are OK. Even if the file descriptor was not valid, I'd expect it to return -1. The code (which is not my own, and it's cross-platform and works fine on Linux) actually checks if the return value is -1 and acts accordingly.

MSDN is extremely unhelpful, and just says:

> [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235412%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)
>
> This POSIX function is deprecated. Use the ISO C++ conformant _[read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyssk1bs.aspx) instead.

But, I just tried and replaced `read` with `_read`, and it works perfectly.

- What exactly is the difference between `read` and `_read`? Since `read` is not documented, I can't just look it up. It seems to do the same, but also raises exceptions.
- Can I just mix "deprecated POSIX functions" and "ISO C++ conformant"* ones? For example "open" and "_read"? It seems to work fine
- Can I just `#define read _read` and so on, and expect it to work just like on Linux?

---

*) Note that the project is plain C, not C++, despite the language in the documentation. MSVC is wierd in that it is not really C or C++, but C/C++ in a sense. Also, the fact that exceptions are raised does not mean I am using C++, but it is a non-standard windows extension of C, IIRC.

Comment: there is no such thing as `plain c` it's just c. don't write `c/c++` you can instead write `c and/or c++` or something similar, there are very important differences between the two languages, it's NOT like `c++` is just `c` with classes and templates.

Comment: You believe? Did you check the parameters? There's no difference between `read()` and `_read()`.

Comment: You can make the warning disappear by adding `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE=1` to the preprocessor definitions ( see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235384.aspx ). `read` and `_read` should behave exactly the same, so if replacing one with the other does something for you, you're probably chasing some (possibly) unrelated UB.

Comment: @iharob: I'm aware of that (especially that C is not just a subset of C++). I am using C here, not C++. But the C standard function `read` behaves strangely for me under MSVC, and MSDN tells me to use what it calls the "ISO C++ function" `_read` *in my C program*. The point is that Microsoft's compiler and documentation mixes up C and C++. It's not my confusion, but that of MSVC.

Comment: As far as I know, `_read` is not part of C++. I guess "ISO C++ conformant" means using a reserved identifier. As `<unistd.h>` isn't a C++ standard header, I don't see how an unreserved identifier can become an issue, however (wrt C++ conformance).

Comment: For the `#define`: It's probably better to use a static wrapper function (if it turns out to be better to use the non-POSIX `_read` on Windows). `read` (a rather common word) could easily be some member function or declared in some other namespace, a macro would also expand e.g. for `foo.read()` or `foo::read()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just `#define read _read` and so on, and expect it to work just like on Linux?

Yes, just do it, it will solve the problem, and your code will be cross platform, just remember that there are other functions with the same issue.